# Illegal offset type in isset or empty Doctrine clear

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I search for hours to find solution for this problem but without luck.

Maybe this is duplicate post, but I didn't find it.

So, I have problem in **Symfony's Service**, when I call entity manager `clear($entityname)` method I got this error:

```
Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty.
```

I have no clue why this happening.

If i comment `clear()` method, everything works fine.

First I call `ProductController`

```
public function postProductAction(Request $request)
{
    if($jsonData = $this->requestToArray($request)){
        $productHandler = $this->get("admin.product_handler");
        $insertNews = $productHandler->insert($jsonData);
        if($insertNews === true) {
            return $this->jsonResponse->setData(array(
            "status" => true, "msg" => MessageConstants::SUCCESS_SEND_DATA));
        }
    }
    $this->jsonResponse->setStatusCode(204);
    return $this->jsonResponse->setData(
    array("status" => false, "msg" => MessageConstants::FAILED_RECEIVE_RESPONSE));
}
```

Then call `ProductHandler` which set new product

```
 $productRepo = new Products();
 $productRepo->setCarmodels(json_encode($data['ModelId']));
 $productRepo->setCategoryid($category);
 $productRepo->setDescription($data['Description']);
 $productRepo->setDiscount($data['Discount']);
 $productRepo->setDiscountprice($data['DiscountPrice']);
 $this->em->persist($productRepo);
 $this->em->flush($productRepo);
 $insertOther = $this->update($productRepo->getId(), $data);
 $this->em->clear($productRepo);
```

`insertAnotfer` call update,because there is some action which require to get product id, so I need first to insert then do update.

```
$product = $productRepo->find((int)$id);
$product->setCarmodels(json_encode($data['ModelId']));
$product->setCategoryid($category);
$product->setDescription($data['Description']);
$product->setDiscount($data['Discount']);
$product->setDiscountprice($data['DiscountPrice']);
```

In update I also call clear method

```
$this->em->flush($product);
$this->em->clear($product);
```

And then I get this error. I tried to remove clear method from update but no luck. Error will not be trigger only if I set `clear()` method without entity in insert function.

Comment: Could you please edit your post, and show the full code and where the problem occurs. Only show the code/files where you are clearing the entity though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EntityManager::clear method takes the name of an entity type, not an actual instance of an entity:

**\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager**:

```
 /**
 * Clears the EntityManager. All entities that are currently managed
 * by this EntityManager become detached.
 *
 * @param string|null $entityName if given, only entities of this type will get detached
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function clear($entityName = null)
{
    $this->unitOfWork->clear($entityName);
}
```

It seems like what you need is detach - the correct method for disassociating an entity instance from the entity manager:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities

**\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager**:

```
 /**
 * Detaches an entity from the EntityManager, causing a managed entity to
 * become detached.  Unflushed changes made to the entity if any
 * (including removal of the entity), will not be synchronized to the database.
 * Entities which previously referenced the detached entity will continue to
 * reference it.
 *
 * @param object $entity The entity to detach.
 *
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws ORMInvalidArgumentException
 */
public function detach($entity)
{
    if ( ! is_object($entity)) {
        throw ORMInvalidArgumentException::invalidObject('EntityManager#detach()' , $entity);
    }

    $this->unitOfWork->detach($entity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you should have the parameter specified within either the flush or clear functions.

Have you tried like this (without entity as parameter):

```
$this->em->flush();
$this->em->clear();
```

I'm not certain if that will work for you, but can you try it and see if that helps? I could be wrong about this though, so if someone has a better suggestion, please post.

Comment: That only work if I remove clear from update method, and call flush and clear as you suggest. But problem is not solved, because I need to have those methods in update too.